# How to adjust an Anchor Point in a Mesh Object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, gradient-mesh

I'm working on my personal project. My basic element (a bar) needed to be responsive in shape changing. First thing I applied the bar in is something like this:

[image]

And the blue things (bar), the thing I wanted to do with is changing the shape to a rectangle. To reduce time and file size, on the process of making the bar, instead of blurring background by copy the picture and make a clipping mask, I created a gradient mesh. But when I start to change the shape of the whole bar, the problem came. I can't change the anchor point of the mesh object, to make a rectangle. When I click an anchor point, it always shows "mesh point" instead.

[image]

So... Could you tell me how to solve the problem?
Thanks and appreciate your answers!
PS: Sorry if there are some grammars errors! Hope you help me!

Answer (score 1):

Mesh anchors and handles can be altered by using the **Convert Anchor Point Tool**, the same way you alter standard anchors.

The only caveat is that mesh anchors can not be converted to/from smooth points/corner points.. they are *all* mesh points. You can use the Convert Anchor Point Tool and drag a mesh anchor's handles into the anchor, essentially creating a corner point.

Answer (score 0):

I can't indicate if this solution works, since I'm not able to see your layers tab at the right side of your workplace, but since you said it can't be changed, two things might happen in the process of what you're doing, 1. Layer you want to edit is locked (If yes, go check your layer's tab and unlock the layer first so that you can edit the embedded image/shape's anchor point). 2. Your meshed layer is in another meshed image (If yes, double click on  the image/shape and then your meshed image which you can't edit previously should have a yellow color on anchors which should mean that it can now be edited, if still no, check on the layers tab again, and it should give you options to unlock it).

Image below is my version of Adobe Illustrator, "Layers" tab should be somewhere n your lower right workplace. If not go to Window > Layers.
[image]

Comment: I've unlock all the things in layers tab before asking you guys. When I click the mesh Object, only that mesh Object is highlighted. The things I want to do is change the shape. For example, the original shape of bar and gradient mesh, I just need to convert the anchor point (that I wanted) to straight instead of curve.

Comment: @jacker07 Use the convert anchor point tool to make the anchor a corner.  If you can't find it, it'll be hidden under the pen tool.